# C++ if use a block of memory not requested by new?what will happen?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, new-operator

if i apply for a block of memory by operator new, but move the pointer and use that memory,is that correct?what will happen?

code like this:

```
int *p = new int(1);
p[1] = 2;
p[2] = 3;
p[3] = 4;
```

Comment: Undefined Behavior. In the worst case the program will appear to work fine giving you a false belief that your code is correct.

Comment: It will come back to haunt you, probably at the worst possible time. Code seems to work perfectly, until you need to demo it, turn in the assignment, or it makes it to production. :)

Comment: It's the least of your problems, but it's worth mentioning that `new int(1);` allocates an `int` on the heap and assigns the value of `1` to that int, whereas `new int[1];` (note *square brackets*) allocates an array-of-ints that is 1 item long.  I suspect you meant to do the latter, not the former.

Answer (score 0):

> is that correct?

It's not a correct program.

> what will happen?

Anything, or everything, or nothing. The behaviour of the program is undefined.